# How to update the database schema in a production environment?

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine

I'm working in a project synchronized with a remote repository. I execute this command to update the database on my localhost (development environment):

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

but I've read on Doctrine documentation that it shouldn't be executed on a production environment, so I have to execute now the SQL command directly on my production database.

The problem is that I'm not sure what columns I've changed, so I'm looking for a way to know the differences between those databases. Any idea?

Comment: Its simple update schema in dev env and then clear all the cache and of project and then hit your project url so new mapping will be saved for production env

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid - I'm not sure what are you suggesting. The "`schema:update`" has altered some tables, so it is not enough clearing the cache.

Comment: The update command with --force will work just fine in a production environment.  Just make a backup first and then make sure you run your clearcache stuff after.

Comment: @Cerad - And why it is said to not use in a production environment?

Comment: I have often wondered that myself.  Tradition?  I always get a chuckle over the fact that it warns you then goes ahead and does it anyways.  You would think it would give you a "are your sure" prompt if it was truly dangerous.  Any sort of update to a production site runs the risk of causing problems.

Comment: @Cerad - All right. Thanks for your opinion. I was also wondering the same ;)

Answer (score 1):

Better is use DB versioning system (doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle)

Another way - make full db dump to dev environment than make

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
```

And start queries on live

Comment: I have `doctrine-migrations-bundle` installed. Do you mean to execute `php app/console doctrine:migrations:migrate`?

Comment: Yes, but you should first make migrations to migrate

Comment: ¿"Make migrations to migrate"? Could you please extend your answer? I'm very new to this bundle... The project on which I'm working is an existing project and it seems to use this migration system.

Comment: @Manolo first do `php app/console make:migration` or for newer versions: `php bin/console make:migration`. Then do your command.